# Reading from a file in a for loop with batch in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch program that will go search through a directory tree and find video files that are unplayable and remove them. Everything seems to work fine, I run ffmpeg and send its output to a txt file. When I read from the txt file it works fine the first time. All the reads after the first one are incorrect and seem to copy the result from the previous read.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set ext=.avi .mkv .mp4
for /R %%i in (*.*) do ( 
    for %%a in (%ext%) do (
        if "%%a" == "%%~xi" (
            echo found video file "%%i", scanning integrity...
            ffmpeg.exe -v error -i "%%i" -f null - >output.txt 2>&1
            set /p error= < output.txt
            if "!error!" == "" (
                echo +video is good
            ) else (
                echo -video is bad... deleting it
                echo "(delete here)"
            )

        )
    )
)
pause
```

With all the things that have been pointed out, I've been able to greatly simplify my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /R %%i in (*.avi *.mkv *.mp4) do ( 
    echo found video file "%%i", scanning integrity...
    ffmpeg.exe -v error -i "%%i" -f null -
    if "!errorlevel!" == "0" (
        echo +video is good
    ) else (
        echo -video is bad... deleting it
        echo "(delete here)"
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: A little tip for you. `for /R %%i in (*.avi *.mkv *.mp4) do (`

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not easy to reproduce your problem, I propose

```
        ffmpeg.exe -v error -i "%%i" -f null - >output.txt 2>&1
        SET "ERROR="
        set /p error= < output.txt
```

The issue with `set /p` is that *no* input leaves the variable *unchanged*, it does not set to to *nothing*.

? have you examined the value of `errorlevel` after `ffmpeg` ? If it follows the rules, `errorlevel` should be `0` on success and non-0 on error.

Comment: It appears that adding the `SET "ERROR="` fixed the problem. There is no input when the file is valid, which made valid file appear to be invalid. When adding in `echo %errorlevel%` it always returned 0.

Comment: I'm not surprised. You need to learn about `delayed expansion` - that's the reason for `%varname%` and `!varname!` in your code. After `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, `%varname% yields the value of `varname` at the time the `code block` (parenthesised sequence of lines - very outermost, the `for...%%i...`) was entered. `!varname!` gives you the value as it currently stands. Try `echo !errorlevel!` instead. No guarantees though.

Comment: And what happen if you add `echo !errorlevel!` instead? (like in your `if "!error!" == "" (` line)...

Comment: Adding `echo !errorlevel!` does echo 1 on failure as expected. I was using `%var%` until very recently when I found out about delayed expansion then I changed all my variables to use `!var!` instead after understanding the functionality. I forgot about it and reverted back to my old habit when adding the errorlevel check.

Comment: So...`if errorlevel 1 (do error things) else (do good things)` Simples.

Comment: @Jake, if you use the code changes suggested by myself and Magoo, it decreases the amount of code you are using and should speed up your script considerably.